# Why won't my attribute selectors override my previous combinator selectors?

Tags: html, css, attributes

Problem Description: I have some form fields set up in HTML. I used combinators to set these blocks to `display:block` so they would stack on top of each other vertically.

```
.signup-form label,
.signup-form select,
.signup-form input {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Later on, I decided to use attribute selectors to change them to `display:inline-block` instead.

```
.signup-form input[id="agree-terms"],
.signup-form input[for="agree-terms"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
```

This did not successfully change the elements to inline-blocks and I'm not sure why. My codepen link is down below. Thank you!

https://codepen.io/NFuego24-7/pen/BaLGWRb

Comment: `input[for="agree-terms"]` <-- typo `label[for="agree-terms"]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I initially thought input[ ] was required for both since form fields are usually for user inputs. (*pleb alert). Much obliged!